# Unable to consume Odata service in a Phonegap IOS Project?

Tags: ios, cordova, odata, cordova-2.0.0

I am trying consume a Odata service using datajs-1.0.0.js using the code below.It runs well in a browser.

```
        OData.read("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers('ALFKI')/Orders",
                function(data){

                    alert('oData Function');

                    var str;
                    alert('before for');
                    for(var objRec in data.results){
                        var obj = data.results[objRec];

                        str = str + ' '+obj.OrderID;
                    }
                    alert(str);
                    alert('after for');
                }, function (err) {
                    alert(err.message);
                });
```

Now I need to run it in a Phonegap IOS Project (version Cordova 2.4) however nothings happens.It does not throw any error as well. I have added the URL in the config.xml file of phonegap to allow external host.

```
    <access origin="*" />
```

The same code works fine when I run it in Android Phonegap Project.

Is there anything that I have missed out?

Answer (score 0):

Does setting the OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView to YES or upgrading to datajs 1.1.0 solve the problem?

Comment: I am using datajs.1.1.0.js. Also have tried setting  OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView to YES, but no Luck.

Comment: I have one only one idea left. Do you wait for the deviceready state of PhoneGap? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#deviceready

Comment: Yes. I am calling the service when the device ready event is fired.